# BackgroundDownloader doesn't download entire file?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm following the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj152726.aspx) for using the BackgroundDownloader class, I've uploaded a large file (50 MB) on dropbox and used it's url to download.

What happened is that the downloader downloaded only 30 KB from the file.

are there any restrictions on the download size ? what can be wrong here ?

Comment: Did any errors got reported? If so which?

Comment: Did you look at that 30kB? It could be an Error page.

Comment: First thing here is to reproduce it without DropBox. Host the file on IIS/localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my fault, I had to out the files in Dropbox Public folder, it worked just fine.

Sorry for the inconvenience, thanks for your help